# Data field is missing from HTTP response object. How can I access it?

Tags: javascript, http, model-view-controller, service, undefined

I want to access the order data by using

`$scope.hero.order = response.data;`

But it gives an error of undefined and when I check the response object there is no `data` field which is normally presents , Can anybody highlight my mistake?

[image: Image is shown]

**OrderService.js**

```
angular.module('Orders')
    .service('OrderService', ['$http', '$state', '$resource', '$q', 'SettingService', '$localStorage', "MessageService",
     function($http, $state, $resource, $q, SettingService, $localStorage, MessageService) {
        var orderResource = $resource(SettingService.baseUrl + "api/orders/:id", {id:'@id'}, {'query':{method:'GET', isArray:false}, 'update':{method:'PATCH'}});
        var service = {
getOrder : function(OrderId, successCallback, failureCallback){
                orderResource.query({id:OrderId}, successCallback, failureCallback);
         }
        }
        return service;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get "error of undefined" because the first argument of `orderResource.query()`'s success callback is the response body (order object in your case), not response object. So, your success callback function should look like:

```
function(order, getResponseHeaders, status, statusText) {
  $scope.hero.order = order;
  ...
}
```

You can refer to `$resource`'s [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> Success callback is called with (value (Object|Array), responseHeaders (Function), status (number), statusText (string)) arguments

What you do now (try to get order object from `response.data`) is the behavior of `$http` ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)) -- `$http`'s success callback will receive a `response` object, whose `data` field refer to the http response body. However, it is different for `$resource` -- body, headers, status etc. are all passed as parameter in sequence.

It seems AngularJS should align the behavior, but unfortunately it doesn't.